# How to create a drag and drop link with favicon

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarks, favicon, favorites

We are working on a link that can be added to the bookmarks menu of most web browsers, we have successfully created one that even executes some javascript to insert code into the website that is in display at that moment (like pinterest).

Is it possible to add code to this link so it can create reference towards a favicon in order to be shown on the bookmarks bar?, the idea is to drag this link towards the bookmarks bar and show the name of the site + the favicon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the bookmark is a link to the website, then the browser should show a favicon once they've visited the URL (assuming the site has a favicon set up properly).

If the bookmark is actually a JavaScript bookmarklet that gets run when clicked form any page, then no I don't believe a favicon can be shown in that case.